# Singularity structure of function in the complex plane.

Tags: complex-analysis, functions

Consider a piecewise differentiable function $f(x):\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$. Now, analytically continue this function ($x\to z$) to complex argument and values $f(z):\mathbb{C}\to\mathbb{C}$. For such a function, is the following statement true, and if yes why?

Statement:

- If $f(z)$ has poles in the complex plane at points $z_p$ with $\Im(z_p)\neq0$, then these poles always appear symmetrically in pairs in the upper and lower halfplane and these pairs have residues of equal absolute value and opposite sign.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Piecewise differentiable is not nearly good enough, the restriction of a holomorphic function to the real axis is real-analytic.

But if you start with a real-analytic function $\sum a_n x^n$, sure, you can extend it like that ("$x \to z$"), at least in some neighborhood of the real axis. You might be able to extend it analytically even more, even if the expression no longer converges.

In any case, the analytic function you get will be symmetric with respect to the real axis, in the sense that $f(\overline{z}) = \overline{f(z)}$. So yes, everything about it will be "symmetric". I'll let you check that this means that your pairs of poles (or essential singularities) will have in fact conjugate residues (and not opposite)